# Android Studio: Gradle не строит проект

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Обновил Android Studio до 3.0.1. Теперь не могу создать проект для Android ниже версии 4.0. Создал проект для Android 4.0.4. Почему то когда запускаю моё приложение (кстати это дефолтный hellow world) Gradle всегда думает минуты 2 и говорит:

> Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 2m 9s 220ms

Может из за этого:
[image: Gradle]
И как это устранить?

---

Лог Gradle:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\tooltip.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable\abc_btn_colored_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_000.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_right_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\color\abc_secondary_text_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable\abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\color\abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\color\abc_primary_text_material_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\anim\tooltip_enter.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl_dark.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_ic_star_black_36dp.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-26.1.0.aar\936058fded3a908b488c92e99ed2dd9c\res\layout\notification_template_lines_media.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\8bdb59c6316f82b1f69cb14381205d26\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\color-v23\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable\abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\8bdb59c6316f82b1f69cb14381205d26\res\layout\notification_template_custom_big.xml: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png: error: file not found.
C:\Users\???????? ??????\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\9d61cd38b3929437e6a75a9324934659\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
8 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 7 up-to-date
----------
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ошибки-то какие градл пишет?

Comment: @woesss Кстати в пути к проекту нет русских и не ascii символов. Лог я добавил в вопрос

Comment: @woesss лог я добавил в вопрос

Comment: У Вас имя юзера в системе по-русски задано - некоторые приложения этого не любят. Лучше сменить. Хотя для конкретно этого случая можно попробовать поменять путь к папке кэша градла (где-то в настройках есть)

Comment: А сначала попробуйте File->Invalidate Caches/Restart и ребилд проекта

Comment: почему вы считаете, что именно инструмент тупой. Данный инструмент устанавливают тысячи разработчиков, а проблемы не решаемые без посторонней помощи именно у вас. Это я к тому, что в публичных местах не стоит употреблять такие обороты речи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Поймал аналогичную проблему.

Решил переносом кешей градла в папку, где нет кириллических символов. Делается это в настройках студии

settings -> build, execution deployment -> gradle

Поле service directory path.

Потом синхронизировать проект и градл

Comment: Как синхронизировать Gradle?